# In ASP.NET Core MVC, how do you make uploaded images accessible to logged users in app but not to general public?

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc

I have image upload in my system. I am struggling to understand what is the logic of serving images.

1. If I upload directly to `wwwroot`, the files will be accessible to everyone, which is not what I want.
2. I understand I could save the file contents in the database as base64 but those can be big files, and I would like them on the server in files.
3. I could convert them on the fly when requested. Most probably getting the path to file, then loading it in a memory stream and spitting out the base64. But seems overkill, and not an elegant solution. I use Automapper for most data and I have to write some crazy custom mappers, which I will If there is no other way.
4. I could create virtual path, which from what I understand maps physical path on server to a `url` which doesn't seem any different than `option 1`

I fancy there is a way to spit out a link/url that this user has access to (or at least logged users) that can be passed to the app so it can load it. Is this impossible or unreasonable? Or am I missing something?

What is the correct way of doing in general?

Also, what is a quick way to do it without spending days for setup?

Answer (score 0):

To protect the specific static files, you can try the solutions explained in [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#static-file-authorization).

***Solution A***: Store static files you want to authorize outside of `wwwroot`, and call `UseStaticFiles` to specify a path and other `StaticFileOptions` after calling `UseAuthorization`, then set the fallback authorization policy.

***Solution B***: Store static files you want to authorize outside of `wwwroot`, and serve it via a controller action method to which authorization is applied and return a `FileResult` object.